# install wordpress in osx with nginx and php failed

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, nginx

*problem solved*

I want to install wordpress osx.

These are what I done.

1. `$ brew install nginx`
2. `$ brew install --without-apache --with-fpm --with-mysql php55`
3. download latest wordpress.zip and extract to /var/www/wordpress_test
4. run php-fpm by `php-fpm -g /usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.pid`
5. write nginx config files like this.

/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log /usr/local/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  256;
}

http {
    include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /usr/local/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/site-enabled/*;
}
```

/usr/local/etc/nginx/site-avaiable/wordpress_test

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /usr/local/log/nginx/wordpress_test.access.log;
    error_log  /usr/local/log/nginx/wordpress_test.error.log;

    root   /var/www/wordpress_test;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

1. create symlink `/usr/local/nginx/site-available/wordpress_test` to ` usr/local/nginx/site-enabled/wordpress_test
2. create `/var/www/wordpress_test/info.php` and write inside it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

And I can see php info by accessing `http://localhost:8080/info.php`.
But I get error message when I access `http://localhost:8080/index.php`.

`/usr/local/log/nginx/wordpress_test.error.log` doesn't put any message.
and `/usr/local/log/nginx/wordpress_test.access.log` shows this message.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2013:17:21:55 +0900] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 500 537 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36"
```

How can I solve this problem? What should I check next?

--
I add settings like this from http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx, then it works.

```
# WordPress single blog rules.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.

# This order might seem weird - this is attempted to match last if rules below fail.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Uncomment one of the lines below for the appropriate caching plugin (if used).
#include global/wordpress-wp-super-cache.conf;
#include global/wordpress-w3-total-cache.conf;

# Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
location ~ \.php$ {
    # Zero-day exploit defense.
    # http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
    # Won't work properly (404 error) if the file is not stored on this server, which is entirely possible with php-fpm/php-fcgi.
    # Comment the 'try_files' line out if you set up php-fpm/php-fcgi on another machine.  And then cross your fingers that you won't get hacked.
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be your .htaccess file not working with nginx, Have you converted your wordpress .htaccess file to nginx configuration ?

Please see the url http://winginx.com/htaccess for .htaccess to nginx conf converter.

Answer (score 0):

just add a new location to your `/usr/local/etc/nginx/site-avaiable/wordpress_test`

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I add the setting and do `nginx -s reload`. but It doesn't work yet.

Comment: did you call it with sudo ?

Comment: No, in osx I don't need it. As I edited the question I solved the problem. But thanks anyway!